# how to remove key constraint of column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

> how to remove key from column in Mysql?(primary,foreign,unique all)

here i given primary key to the column **id**

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id);
```

now i like to remove it, and make none key column **id**
is there is any way.i used,

```
 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `id` INT
```

but it actually gives UNIQUE key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
 ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `id` INT ;
 ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: yes `ALTER TABLE 'table' MODIFY 'id' INT ;`it works but it gives UNIQUE  key so that i don't want . see after executing Query the result is`FIELD=id   TYPE=int(11)     COLLATION=(null)  NULL=yes    KEY=UNI`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can run the below command :

Alter TABLE `tableName` MODIFY COLUMN  id INT, DROP PRIMARY KEY;

```css
mysql> desc TestTable;

+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.05 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE TestTable MODIFY COLUMN id INT(10),DROP PRIMARY KEY;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.62 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc TestTable;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Can you format this properly. It's hard to tell what it says.

Comment: thanks it works...but is there is only one **Query** to delete all type of key From table?

Comment: @Akib Bagwan : Yes by using Alter command you can drop keys from the table.

Comment: i need a Query. but only one query that will affect to all(ie. primary,unique &  FOREIGN KEY remove from column).